# How do I conditionally create a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

As part of my integration strategy, I have a few SQL scripts that run in order to update the database. The first thing all of these scripts do is check to see if they need to run, e.g.:

```
if @version <> @expects
    begin
        declare @error varchar(100);
        set @error = 'Invalid version. Your version is ' + convert(varchar, @version) + '. This script expects version ' + convert(varchar, @expects) + '.';
        raiserror(@error, 10, 1);
    end
else
    begin
        ...sql statements here...
    end
```

Works great! Except if I need to add a stored procedure. The "create proc" command must be the only command in a batch of sql commands. Putting a "create proc" in my IF statement causes this error:

```
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

Ouch! How do I put the CREATE PROC command in my script, and have it only execute if it needs to?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

Wrap it in an EXEC(), like so:

```
if @version <> @expects
    begin
        ...snip...
    end
else
    begin
        exec('CREATE PROC MyProc AS SELECT ''Victory!''');
    end
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Re-creating procs every time (conditionally dropping) is a much better solution.  If use exec, you gain nothing and there are downsides; your proc has to escape strings and any line numbers in errors will refer to the line number relative to the exec command.

Comment: +1 for being able to handle conditions other than existence (in my case @@Version drives whether certain procs are created or not)

Comment: +1 - I used this to configure my CRUD generator to create a stub procedure if it did not already exist, and _then_ alter it. This allows me to amend my stored procs, build the CRUD but _preserve any permissions assigned against existing procs_.

Answer (score 11):

SET NOEXEC ON is good way to switch off some part of code

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'SQL_CLR_Functions')
  SET NOEXEC ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CLR_CharList_Split(@list nvarchar(MAX), @delim nchar(1) = N',')
RETURNS TABLE (str nvarchar(4000)) AS EXTERNAL NAME SQL_CLR_Functions.[Granite.SQL.CLR.Functions].CLR_CharList_Split
GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Found here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/conditional-create-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch

P.S. Another way is SET PARSEONLY { ON | OFF }.

Comment: Love this solution, as the procedure I was trying to create already had dynamic sql in it. Dynamically creating dynamic sql is not lot of fun.

Comment: SET PARSEONLY ON is interpreted at parse time, not execution time, and does not work in the if statement (i.e. it turns it on regardless of whether the IF condition is true or false)

Answer (score 5):

But watch out for single quotes within your Stored Procedure - they need to be "escaped" by adding a second one.  The first answer has done this, but just in case you missed it.  A trap for young players.

Comment: this answer should be a comment. Why don't you move it there?

Answer (score 3):

Versioning your database is the way to go, but...  Why conditionally create stored procedures.  For Views, stored procedures, functions, just conditionally drop them and re-create them every time. If you conditionally create, then you will not clean-up databases that have a problem or a hack that got put in 2 years ago by another developer (you or I would never do this) who was sure he would remember to remove the one time emergency update.

Comment: because recreating loses metadata such as created date

Answer (score 2):

Problem with dropping and creating is you lose any security grants that had previously been applied to the object being dropped.

Comment: It's only a problem if you don't also re-add those grants after the procedure is re-created ;-).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but Jobo is incorrect:  Create Procedure must be the first statement in a batch.  Therefore, you can't use `Exists` to test for existence and then use either `Create` or `Alter`.  Pity.

Comment: True :) (Btw, that should probably be a comment, rather than an answer. But I understand you cannot "comment" yet ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is much better to alter an existing stored proc because of the potential for properties and permissions that have been added AND which will be lost if the stored proc is dropped.

So, test to see if it NOT EXISTS, if it does not then create a dummy proc. Then after that use an alter statement.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'YOUR_STORED_PROC_NAME' AND xtype='P')
EXECUTE('CREATE PROC [dbo].[YOUR_STORED_PROC_NAME] as BEGIN select 0 END')
GO
ALTER  PROC [dbo].[YOUR_STORED_PROC_NAME]
....
```

Comment: Still, this one alters the procedure in case if it existed. What if somebody has already created a newer version of it? How to avoid altering the procedure if it already exists and creating a new one only if it does not exist, to avoid losing the existing procedure code?

Comment: @JustAMartin, This is not version control but simply an Alter or Create statement. I'm not aware of any native or built in version control for SQL Server, or any other database. I think one would need to create something. Perhaps a custom property, something in the comments of the stored proc itself? My point here is that always dropping a proc if it already exists potentially loses important attributes that are not reinstated with the create.

Comment: @JustAMartin I see that I misread your comment. If one only wishes to create a stored proc when one with the same name does not exist then just use create. It will fail if the proc is already defined.

Comment: @JustAMartin I see that I misread your comment. If one only wishes to create a stored proc when one with the same name does not exist then just use create. It will fail if the proc is already defined.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem with MS SQL Server;  there's no clean way to tell it - if the sproc exists, then just skip it (and also don't throw errors - just skip attempting to update it).

Answer (score 1):

I must admit, I would normally agree with @Peter - I conditionally drop and then unconditionally recreate every time. I've been caught out too many times in the past when trying to second-guess the schema differences between databases, with or without any form of version control.

Having said that, your own suggestion @Josh is pretty cool. Certainly interesting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to check if the proc exists, if so then drop it, and then create the proc (same answer as @robsoft but with an example...)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'PROC_NAME' AND xtype='P') 
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE PROC_NAME
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME
    @value  int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  SomeTable
    SET     SomeColumn = 1
    WHERE   Value = @value
END
GO
```

Comment: So, in case if the procedure existed, we are deleting it. But what if it was a newer, better version of the procedure? It's not nice to just blindly drop and overwrite it. In many cases, if it already exists and we didn't expect it to exist, then just leave it alone and do some investigation to see where did it come from and if you really can overwrite it.

Comment: My question would be why are people editing scripts on the server without committing those changes to source control. How do they know that their changes won't be blindly overwritten by some other actor? If this solution doesn't work for you then don't use it, but coming here to complain that it doesn't fit your specific use-case doesn't help anyone, and honestly if you have people directly editing procs on your SQL Server without committing those changes to source control then you have bigger problems IMO.

Comment: I'm not complaining, just cautioning, because I've been in nasty situations when some large old project management is messed up and there are two or more separate developers of different companies maintaining copies of the same database in different environments. Thus a sproc might exist on one server but not on another, so it is necessary to apply a script that doesn't do anything at all (not fail, not alter), in case if the sproc already exists, and creates a new one if it doesn't. But yeah, you are right, it shouldn't be necessary, if you have good management and single source of authority.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'pr_MyStoredProc')
BEGIN

     CREATE PROCEDURE pr_MyStoredProc AS .....
     SET NOCOUNT ON
END

ALTER PROC pr_MyStoredProc
AS
SELECT * FROM tb_MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

use the 'Exists' command in T-SQL to see if the stored proc exists. If it does, use 'Alter', else use 'Create'