# Using SQL user defined function in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, user-defined-functions

I am very new to Access and need a bit help over here.
I was working on MS Access 2007 (in VB) with SQL 2008 Server as my database.

I wanted to show a SQL table in the frontend of Access but faced the problem while using SQL user defined function with my SQL query in Access 2007. I wrote this function and the query in SQL Query design of Access and tried to Run it.. but its showing error (Userdefined "timepart" function not recognized) !!

```
CREATE function  dbo.timepart (@date as SMALLDATETIME) 
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME 
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN @date - DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d,0,@date), 0) 
END 

SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE dbo.timepart(FIELDNAME) Between '9:30' AND '17:30';
```

I guess MS Access doesn't allow to write UDF SQL functions! I tried this same query in my local SQL Server 2008 database (SQL management studio) and is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [pass-through](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968) query. With a pass-through query, the code is run on SQL Server and the results are returned to MS Access. You can therefore use SQL Server T-SQL.

Also [access-SQL pass-through query (creating SP) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197870/access-sql-pass-through-query-creating-sp-error/12198827#12198827)

[image: set up odbc]

Comment: I chose the "pass through" tab and then executed the query. Its now asking me to "Select data source" !!

Comment: Did you set up the ODBC connection?

Comment: Yes I did !! Is there any other option?? Can I log into my online database server, create this function and use it directly in the SQL Query Desing of Access !!??

Comment: You can create a view in SQL Server and link that and you can run a stored procedure with ADO or in the query design window as a pass-through query. However, if you cannot get a simple pass-through query to work, such as shown above, you need to sort out that problem. For a start, are you using linked tables?

Comment: No, I am not using linked tables.

Comment: How are you connecting to SQL server? Are you using *.accdb or *.mdb? Any reason why you are not working using the MS recommended linked tables?

Comment: How are you connecting to SQL server?