# VBA ADODB - Get multiple rows affected from single query

Tags: vba, adodb, multiple-records

I am running an update query to SQL Server through VBA using VBA's ADODB connection class. In SQL Server the query returns rows affected which can be accessed in VBA through the ADODB command class.

However I have no idea how to return an array of multiple records affected statements.

I am using the sample code:

```
Dim ADODBconn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsRead As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Rslt_Count As Long

'Set Up Connection and begin SQL Transaction
Set ADODBconn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
ADODBconn.BeginTrans

'Build Update SQL
SQLLine = "******update query that runs on multiple tables here********"

'Execute SQL
ADODBconn.Execute SQLLine, Rslt_Count, dbFailOnError

MsgBox Rslt_Count
ADODBconn.CommitTrans
ADODBconn.Close
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTables
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @RowCount2 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount3 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount4 INTEGER

    UPDATE Table2 Set atext = 'a' WHERE atext='b' 
    SELECT @RowCount2 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table3 Set atext = 'a' WHERE atext='b' 
    SELECT @RowCount3 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table4 Set atext = 'a' WHERE atext='b' 
    SELECT @RowCount4 = @@ROWCOUNT

    SELECT @RowCount2 AS Table2, @RowCount3 AS Table3, @RowCount4 AS Table4
END
```

As per [Return number of rows affected by UPDATE statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103260/return-number-of-rows-affected-by-update-statements)

See also : [access-SQL pass-through query (creating SP) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197870/access-sql-pass-through-query-creating-sp-error/12198827#12198827)

You can then:

```
Dim dbconn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim param As New ADODB.Parameter

Set dbconn = New ADODB.Connection
dbconn.ConnectionString = ServerConLocal

dbconn.Open 

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "updatetables"

rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open cmd

''Records affected
For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Debug.Print fld.Name & " : " & fld
Next
End Sub
```

You can also simply create a pass-through query with the single line:

```
UpdateTables
```

Which might return:

```
    Table2  Table3  Table4
    0       2       0
```

Comment: Wow awesome SQL skills. Thank you sir.