# How to write T-SQL upgrade script with user-defined functions referenced by check constraints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a script that can be run regardless of whether a user-defined function already exists. Per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886759/creating-a-udfuser-define-function-if-is-does-not-exist-and-skipping-it-if-it), I have the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.fn_myFunc') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_myFunc;
go

CREATE FUNCTION fn_myFunc (
    ...
) RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
go
```

The issue is, later on, I have

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_chk_myFunc CHECK (dbo.fn_myFunc(...) = 1)
go
```

So when the `DROP FUNCTION` happens, I get

> Cannot DROP FUNCTION 'dbo.fn_myFunc' because it is being referenced by object 'my_table_chk_myFunc '.

I tried, instead of using `...IS NOT NULL DROP... CREATE FUNCTION` using `...IS NULL CREATE... ALTER FUNCTION`, but either I got the syntax wrong, or it doesn't work.

How do I best get around this?

Comment: The function is used in that **CHECK** constraint - therefore, you cannot drop it. You need to **first** drop the `CHECK` constraint - **then** drop your function!

Comment: Yes, I know.  But I'd like either a dynamic way to find all references to the function so I can drop them and recreate them later, or a method to detect if it exists already and just use an alter.

Comment: Have a look at [`sys.dependencies`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) - that might be what you're looking for

Comment: Wrap the `ALTER` and `CREATE` definitions in an `EXEC()` statement.  [Like so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506/how-do-i-conditionally-create-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server).

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20857526/1411000